# In Telerik Kendo Editor 2017 version, if insertHtml is used after the new line, all BR tags are deleted

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, editor, newline, inserthtml

in Telerik Kendo Editor 2017 version, if insertHtml is used after the new line, all <br /> tags are deleted.
Does anyone have a workaround on this?

https://dojo.telerik.com/UpidAFiK

press enter at the end of the 'test text', then enter a new text and finally press the custom tool

[image]

[image]

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This is probably related to a bug in the version used - [bug link](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/3420). Try with a version after R2 2018. With the earliest available in the dojo playground [(v2019.1.220)](https://dojo.telerik.com/oQiQICed) the example works as expected.